# Automatic timed actions

Tags: strapi

I would like to write a method that checks a few ContentTypes every day at 00:00, e.g. posts that are older than two years should be automatically deactivated or deleted.

My question is: where do I write this method? Is there an example of this?

Thanks in advance!

Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Guide in the docs that explain you how to setup a date to publish an article.

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/scheduled-publication.html#create-a-cron-task

That use the CRON system of Strapi and it's what you will need in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much jim, i have already realized it and it works perfectly! :)